# emberjs component form action

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to authenticate against DRF token.

I've successfully been able to login using an auth app I have created.

I thought I'd be slick and make the login form a component.

Since making it a component however, I'm not able to login and I get an `Assertion failure`.

My  templates/components/auth-login.hbs template looks like so ...

```
<form class='navbar-form navbar-right' {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
<div class="form-group">
{{input id='identification' placeholder='Username' type='text' class='form-control' value=identification}}
{{input id='password' placeholder='Password' type='password' class='form-control' value=password}}
</div>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I also have app/controllers/auth-login.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
        authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';

      this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials).catch((reason) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

It works as an app but not as a component.

If I blank the template,  and use the `auth` route/app instead, it works peachy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. You need to define action `authenticate` in actions hash of `auth-login` component.
Option 2. You can keep `identification`, `password` properties and `authenticate` action in controller. and include the auth-component like below,

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
{{auth-component identification=identification password=password authenticate="authenticate" }}
```

**app/components/auth-component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        authenticate() {
            this.sendAction('authenticate'); //this will call corresonding controller authenticate method through bubbling.
        }
    }
});
```

**app/controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
        authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';

      this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials).catch((reason) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: added `components/auth-login.js` as noted above got "Nothing handled the action 'authenticate'."

Comment: `app/controllers/auth-login.js` - this should be `app/components/auth-login.js` and move the existing code from `app/controllers/auth-login.js` file to corresponding controller